# Adding a reference line in a bar plot

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a line to my chart as an indicator, but unable to think of anyway that I can do it.

```
lrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABC").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("ABC").Range("A2:AE" & lrow), PlotBy:= xlColumns
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="ABC"
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "XYZ"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 11
Set cht = ActiveChart
```

Suppose my data is just like

```
                  John             Jack             Jesse
  Exam 1           5                6                4
  Exam 2           6                7                5
  Exam 3           1                4                9
  Exam 4           3                9                8
  Exam 5           8                6                1
```

You can imagine how a bar chart will look like. Now how do I add a Vertical line in this graph at suppose a value of 25 which will indicate any bar going above 25 and like serve as distinction or excellency line. So each Bar of total three will now have a name and marks scored in each exam. If you take it the other way we can add up each individual exam to come up with the total. So the line I need to plot will work to show if any of these guys total is more than 25. Hope this explains. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to add another column in your worksheet to indicate your new data series (everything will just be `10`, in your case) and include that column when you create your chart. Then you can select the data series and plot it as a line using a secondary axis. Search Google for `Excel chart goal line`.

Comment: @Bond Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you saying column A contains `A, B, C, D, F` and column B contains `5, 6, 1, 3, 8`?

Comment: That was just an example, in real I am dealing with a bigger data set. I'll add it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add another row at the bottom of your data to specify your goal line for the exams:

```
    ╔════════╦══════╦══════╦═══════╗
    ║        ║ John ║ Jack ║ Jesse ║
    ╠════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╣
    ║ Exam 1 ║    5 ║    6 ║     4 ║
    ║ Exam 2 ║    6 ║    7 ║     5 ║
    ║ Exam 3 ║    1 ║    4 ║     9 ║
    ║ Exam 4 ║    3 ║    9 ║     8 ║
    ║ Exam 5 ║    8 ║    6 ║     1 ║
    ║ Goal   ║   25 ║   25 ║    25 ║
    ╚════════╩══════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

2. Use code similar to the following to create your chart:

   ```
   Range("A1:D7").Select
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$D$7"), xlRows
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).ChartType = xlLine
   ```

It should be pretty similar to what you currently have with the exception that just the last data series (the goal, series `6`, in this case) is being changed to a line instead of a stacked bar. You could dynamically insert this value based on the number of rows/series in your source data, similar to what you're doing with `lrow`.

3. This should create a chart like the following (goal line in red at y-axis 25). If you need more control over the positioning/styling of the goal line, it can be formatted or even plotted on a secondary Y axis.

[image]

Comment: How do I change the axis of the goal line as you see I plot the main chart as xlColumns and not rows as in your code.

Comment: As I am plotting by columns, I added a column of data, and my goal line should cut everything or should be above it , like how can I change the axis of the goal line? Or in simple words how can I draw a line cutting all my other bars  and just have a number written on it to indicate my goal number? It will be very helpful if you could advice.